# Webm vs Opus - Quality? - youtube-dl context

Tags: audio, youtube-dl, webm, opus

When I download audio from youtube via youtube-dl:

**A)** if I type `-f bestaudio` I get **webm** files which can't contain musical metadata and can't be played by most apps.

**B)** if I type `-f bestaudio --extract-audio --add-metadata` I get **opus** files which contain musical metadata and can be play by most apps.

I conclude Opus is more useful. However webm and opus files often appear to be slightly different on **Spek** and so I get doubtful since I don't know how to read such subtle difference.

**Questions**

1. Is someone able to explain me in casual language what is occurring in the process within youtube-dl when doing it with option A and when doing it with option B?
2. Which one is finer? Quality as when played online full on is a must, not simply to have fun listening to.
3. Is there any other info that could help me assure to download best unprocessed audio with youtube-dl?

I wish someone is able to help me, I thank you very much in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

webm is a media container similar to mkv, opus is a audio format which can be included in the webm among with video, other audio tracks and subtitles etc..

opus seems to have higher bitrate (better quality) than offered by youtube-dl/newpipe but not so great hardware support, that does not matter for your pc and phone though.

youtube does not offer uncompressed audio/video

Comment: Thank you very much for clarifying :) Wish you're enjoying these first days of the year wherever you are! Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

If you're getting webm files (with .webm extension) with the bestaudio parameter that means, you're downloading Opus audio files in webm (matroska) containers:

```
$ youtube-dl -f bestaudio 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LXb3EKWsInQ'
[youtube] LXb3EKWsInQ: Downloading webpage
[download] Destination: COSTA RICA IN 4K 60fps HDR (ULTRA HD)-LXb3EKWsInQ.webm
[download] 100% of 4.96MiB in 00:00
$ mediainfo 'COSTA RICA IN 4K 60fps HDR (ULTRA HD)-LXb3EKWsInQ.webm' 
General
Complete name                            : COSTA RICA IN 4K 60fps HDR (ULTRA HD)-LXb3EKWsInQ.webm
Format                                   : WebM
Format version                           : Version 4
File size                                : 4.96 MiB
Duration                                 : 5 min 13 s
Overall bit rate                         : 133 kb/s
Writing application                      : google/video-file
Writing library                          : google/video-file

Audio
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : Opus
Codec ID                                 : A_OPUS
Duration                                 : 5 min 13 s
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Channel layout                           : L R
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 kHz
Bit depth                                : 16 bits
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Language                                 : English
Default                                  : Yes
Forced                                   : No
```

So, it's not correct to say that there's no audio metadata. You can't play the audio in audio players because they consider it to be a video file, but most video players support playing it. For example, it works with vlc, mpv, totem, Google Chrome and Firefox.

When you add the extract audio parameter, an extra step is done: the webm container is replaced by the Ogg container (and the extension is renamed to .opus). The Opus audio contained in the file stays the same:

```
$ youtube-dl -f bestaudio --extract-audio 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LXb3EKWsInQ'
[youtube] LXb3EKWsInQ: Downloading webpage
[download] COSTA RICA IN 4K 60fps HDR (ULTRA HD)-LXb3EKWsInQ.webm has already been downloaded
[download] 100% of 4.96MiB
[ffmpeg] Destination: COSTA RICA IN 4K 60fps HDR (ULTRA HD)-LXb3EKWsInQ.opus
Deleting original file COSTA RICA IN 4K 60fps HDR (ULTRA HD)-LXb3EKWsInQ.webm (pass -k to keep)
$ mediainfo 'COSTA RICA IN 4K 60fps HDR (ULTRA HD)-LXb3EKWsInQ.opus' 
General
Complete name                            : COSTA RICA IN 4K 60fps HDR (ULTRA HD)-LXb3EKWsInQ.opus
Format                                   : Ogg
File size                                : 4.89 MiB
Duration                                 : 5 min 13 s
Overall bit rate                         : 131 kb/s
Writing application                      : Lavf58.76.100

Audio
ID                                       : 2697462219 (0xA0C801CB)
Format                                   : Opus
Duration                                 : 5 min 13 s
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Channel layout                           : L R
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 kHz
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Writing library                          : Lavf58.76.100
Language                                 : English
```

So, both commands download exactly the same audio contents. The difference is that the latter is wrapped in a container that audio players understand.